# Energy at constant Entropy and Volume

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, energy, entropy, free-energy

> The system of constant entropy and constant volume will attain the equilibrium in a state of minimum energy. Why?

I know that:

$\Delta G= \Delta H-T\Delta S$
And at constant volume and entropy: $\Delta G =\Delta U$

But from above equations how can we justify the give statement?

Comment: The fundamental relationship is dU=TdS-PdV

Comment: We can't. $\Delta G$ is of no use here.

Answer (score 1):

A function such that the equilibrium state of a system is determined by its maximum (or minimum) is called a *characteristic function*. There is a whole bunch of those. All they are ultimately derived from the [Second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) after some fiddling around with differentials.

The said law basically postulates that entropy is one such function. But it is only good for *closed* systems, that is, those with constant $U$ and $V$. Other kinds of systems use other kinds of characteristic functions. To derive them, we typically go along the lines of [Legendre transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Thermodynamics). Say, you have $f(x,y,z,\dots)$, which is a characteristic function in the variables $x,y,z,\dots$, and you want to switch from $x$ to $f'_x$ to use it as your independent variable. Then $f-xf'_x$ is a characteristic function in your new variables.

So let's begin with switching from $U$ to another variable. The new characteristic function is
$$S-U\cdot\left({\partial S\over\partial U}\right)_V=S-{U\over\left({\partial U\over\partial S}\right)_V} = S-{U\over T}$$
(Cryptic as it might seem, the identity $\left({\partial U\over\partial S}\right)_V=T$ is true, and moreover, is the *definition* of temperature.)

To bring this characteristic function to a more familiar appearance, we switch the sign (so we'll be looking after a *minimum*, and not maximum, as we did with entropy), then multiply it by $T$, since it is only going to be used in systems with $T=const$ anyway, and get the [Helmholtz energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy) $F=U-TS$. That's what determines the state of equilibrium for fixed $(T,V)$.

Now let's make the final step. Luckily for us, $-S$ is the thermal derivative of $F$, hence the characteristic function in variables $(S,V)$ is
$$F-T\cdot\left({\partial F\over\partial T}\right)_V=F-T\cdot(-S)=F+TS=U$$
just as we were seeking to prove.

So it goes.

One more variable change from $V$ to $P$ will give us Gibbs energy, but that's another story.